# JxBrowser 7.7 SWT - StartDownloadCallback error

Tags: java, download, callback, swt, jxbrowser

I found this solution everywhere, but unfortunately I got error.

```java
browser.set(StartDownloadCallback.class, (params, tell) -> {
            System.out.println("Download");
            params.download().on(DownloadFinished.class, event ->
                    System.out.println("File downloaded!"));
            tell.download(createTempDir().toAbsolutePath());
        });
```

```
error: method set in interface Advisable<P> cannot be applied to given types;
        browser.set(StartDownloadCallback.class, (params, tell) -> tell.close());
               ^
  required: Class<C>,C
  found: Class<StartDownloadCallback>,(params,te[...]ose()
  reason: inference variable C has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: StartDownloadCallback
    lower bounds: BrowserCallback
  where C,P are type-variables:
    C extends BrowserCallback declared in method <C>set(Class<C>,C)
    P extends Callback declared in interface Advisable
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the version of the JxBrowser.
After an upgrade to 7.8, it will work.